# How to terminate eclipse plugin programatically

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am new to Java Plugin env.In my application there is arequirement like some checks should be done befor the plugin launches and if it fails need to terminate the plugin.I have put the check in the start method of Activator.java class and called the stop method from there. but it seems its still launching the RCP.
Can any one suggest me some way?

Comment: You write about both "_plugin_" and "_application_". Which do you mean? Do you want to prevent your application from starting? (You may _not_ call `stop(...)` from `start(...)`!)

Comment: yes I want to prevent my application application from starting if one of the checks fails.will System.exit() work?

Answer (score 0):

How to prevent your application to start depends a lot on the type of tests you must make and the type of feedback you want to give. Having said that, there are typically two places as shown below: "1" is used if you don't want to give any feedback and "2" is used if you want to show a dialog or similar...

```
public class Application implements IApplication {
  public Object start(IApplicationContext context) {
    // =======> 1
    Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
    // =======> 2
    try {
      int returnCode = PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(display, new ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor());
      if (returnCode == PlatformUI.RETURN_RESTART) {
        return IApplication.EXIT_RESTART;
      }
      return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
    } finally {
      display.dispose();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```